# Getting PHP error Warning: fputcsv() expects parameter 2 to be array

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, csv, mysqli

I have `mysql` db with different tables. The data between the tables are linked and I retrieve and display them by using the userid. I used the reference from PHP MYSQLi Displaying all tables in a databases. I used `fputcsv($fp, $val)` for outputting the result in `.csv` file, but I get this error:

> Warning: fputcsv() expects parameter 2 to be array** . This is my code:

```
<?php

    $con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","mytable");

    if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
        echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
    }

    {
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
    }

    $sql = "SELECT user_id FROM tbl_users";
    $users_profile_user_id = mysqli_query($con, $sql); 
    $row = mysqli_fetch_array($users_profile_user_id, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
    $fp = fopen("user_profile_id.csv", "w");

    foreach($row as $val) {
        fputcsv($fp, $val);
    }

    fclose($fp);

?>
```

I also tried replacing **fputcsv($fp, $val)** with var_export($val) and it is showing just 1 entry from database. Now I know why is it displaying error because it is showing a string, but what is the fix to it? How can I take all the entries from database, and display all those elements in .csv file?

Comment: Try a var_dump of $row and see what you get.

Comment: Why didn't you let the formatted edit be?

Comment: tried var_dump of $row, but displaying the same error

Comment: disable that statement `/*fputcsv($fp, $val);*/` and try again. or even replace it `/*fputcsv($fp, $val);*/ var_export($val);` You'll get a better understanding of what `$val` actually contains.

Comment: It contains just 1 entry. user_id contains many entries. How do I fix it?

Comment: What happens if you replace `mysqli_fetch_array` with `mysqli_fetch_assoc`?

Comment: the output is same as before, displaying a single element.

Answer (score 3):

"Warning: fputcsv() expects parameter 2 to be array, string given inon line 17" is a very helpful message.

What that means is that in `fputcsv($fp, $val);`, $val is expected to be an array and it is not.

`$val` is an element of the `$row` array, so there's a problem with your query or the data in the database.

Comment: I think this should be a comment, because it's not a solution! It's only a few infos

Comment: Not every answer is a solution. My answer explains what that error means and gives the logic to work backward from the error message to find the actual cause.

Comment: It contains just 1 entry. user_id contains many entries. How do I fix it?

Answer (score 2):

You have to give it an array so try it like this

```
$sql = "SELECT user_id FROM tbl_users";
$users_profile_user_id = mysqli_query($con, $sql);

$fp = fopen("user_profile_id.csv", "w");

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($users_profile_user_id)) {
    fputcsv($fp, $row);
}

fclose($fp);
```

Comment: Only because you changed variables names the codes doesn't works!

Comment: SELECT * FROM tbl_users.  I need to select just a particular column. Only the no. of errors increased as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Read the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.fputcsv.php)

fputcsv should be array of values, you have a there string.

Comment: Well, there are no. of entries. If I skip foreach and assume it as string, it only gives me 1 output i.e the first entry of user_id in the table and other entries are not outputted.

Comment: I have a small reputation and I can not comment